# React Native IOS app build without Enrolling for Developer Program

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have developed an app on react native android and want to build same for the ios. While building the IOS app, I am facing the signing issue, It is asking for the Provisional profile. When I log in to my apple account, it is saying I was not enrolled in the developer program and for that, I have to pay the enrollment fee.
My question is

1. Is it compulsory to enroll in the Apple Developer program to build and share the app with my friends. It will cost me around $100
2. Is there any way I can build the app without enrolling to developer program

Comment: You can use a free enrolment but the number of devices you can build for is limited and the builds are only valid for 7 days.

Comment: If your RN app can be built with Expo, Expo provides a number of sharing capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Xcode documentation

> All iOS, tvOS, and watchOS apps must be code signed using a
> provisioning profile to launch on a device. macOS apps that use
> certain app services must be signed to launch on your Mac too.

src: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev5a825a1ca

Which means you compulsorily need a provisioning profile for running anything on device and the only way you can create one is by registering for the Apple Developer Program. It is expensive no doubt but that's Apple for you.

Comment: Do they contradict themselves then? "Do I need to enroll to install apps on a device? No." https://developer.apple.com/support/enrollment/#:~:text=Do%20I%20need,with%20Xcode.

Comment: There is apparently something called Xcode Free Provisioning https://steemit.com/xcode/@ktsteemit/xcode-free-provisioning

Comment: Apple makes you pay $100 for the luxury of letting them take 30% off your app. They really know how to make $$$, don't they?